# How to change title of the customly added emotes in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Hiii

I can add a emote by just adding this :

```
<a href="javascript:EmotionsDialog.insert('smiley-frown.gif','emotions_dlg.frown');"><img src="img/smiley-frown.gif" width="18" height="18" border="0" alt="{#emotions_dlg.frown}" title="{#emotions_dlg.frown}" /></a>
```

But when i hover it shows me : `($emotions_dlg.myemote}` .

How can i change it to something like this `myemote`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will just write text what you want instead of `{$emotions_dlg.myemote}`? Not pretty clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use an own plugin (called own_plugin here) you may use the plugin's language file to acces the description to add it to your emoticon

```
<a>...<img onMouseOver="this.alt=tinymce.EditorManager.i18n[en.own_plugin.myemote]" src="img/smiley-frown.gif" width="18" height="18" border="0" alt="{#emotions_dlg.frown}" title="{#emotions_dlg.frown}" /></a>
```

Comment: This aint exactly what i want

Comment: in that case please be a little bit more specific and edit your question